# How to make multiple Auth : users, admins, seller in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I'm creating an big application with laravel and i want the best security of this.

So i wanna make an multiple Authentication for users, admins and sellers in different table like the same name in my database, i have try to do this with an tuto but the tuto for laravel 5 (i'm using laravel 7), so the tuto is expired.

So someone have make this experience in Laravel 6 or 7 ? if yes can you give me the best way of security to do this multiple auth by different table in laravel 7

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel auth guards like this:

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
    //
}
```

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users).

Comment: ok thank you, i'm trying now i will message you after this.

Comment: this is my return : you'r not connected

Comment: @Judikael maybe bcz your credentials are not correct

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60948272/12344897

To this you need create guards, example:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
   ]
```

Comment: i have an guard that specify my model or Merchant but the basic model have not compatibilities with authenticate model, this is one of my probleme

Comment: please show your code :)

Comment: ok ok i will show you

Comment: that it's i have post image you wanna want the guard ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this :

```
 public function pushLoginForm(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::guard('merchant')->attempt(['pseudo' => $request->pseudo, 'password' => $request->password])){
        return 'You\'r connected';
    } else {
        return "you'r not connected";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image][image: class SellerController that registered seller in seller tables and login for seller]

This is my controller that login and register user by table sellers.

```
'merchants' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'merchants',
    ],
    'api_merchants' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'merchants',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
'merchants' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Merchant::class,
    ],
```

this is above my guards